XSLT How can I strip-spaces but keep existing empty-lines
I have a xml file like this, note that there are extra-spaces that I want to remove and new-lines (I mean empty-lines) that I want to preserve:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.example.application</groupId>
    <artifactId>sample-flow-app</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <properties>
                                                    <java.version>17</java.version>
        <vaadin.version>24.3.8</vaadin.version>
        <playwright.version>1.43.0</playwright.version>
    </properties>


    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.4</version>
    </parent>

</project>

And I have a Transformer configured with this xslt:
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>   

What are the modifications I need to do to my xslt so as empty-lines are preserved when transforming my xml
Thanks
Note the output should look like:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.example.application</groupId>
    <artifactId>sample-flow-app</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <vaadin.version>24.3.8</vaadin.version>
        <playwright.version>1.43.0</playwright.version>
    </properties>


    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.4</version>
    </parent>

</project>

EDIT
In order to give more context, I'm using Java to programatically change pom.xml files in maven projects, this is the significant code I'm using
        // Read the file and parse to a Document
        File pomFile = new File("pom.xml");
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = builder.parse(pomFile);

        // Here I do changes with the Document

        // Transform the document to a xml string, and write to the filesystem
        TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory
                .newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = transformerFactory
                .newTransformer(new StreamSource(IOUtils.toInputStream(
                        """
            <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
              <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
              <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
              <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
                <xsl:copy>
                  <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
                </xsl:copy>
              </xsl:template>
            </xsl:stylesheet>
                                    """,
                        "UTF-8")));
        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new FileOutputStream(file));
        transformer.transform(source, result);   



"there are extra-spaces that I want to remove": well, can you precisely define what is an extra-space and what is a space you want to preserve and how you expect to communicate that to the XML parser and/or XSLT processor?

Well, I don't know what exactly you ask, but basically, my xslt seems to work that it removes all text nodes, and then it applies the format. So that is the reason why if I have wrong indentation, like tabs, or lines extra-indented, it fixes it, which is alright, but still I would like to preserve when it formats those previous new-lines I have to separate sections. I'm not a expert on xslt so actually I cannot ellaborate a better approach, I tried docs and examples to figure out how to fix, but not success, this is the reason I'm asking

Which XSLT processor do you use? And if you can't explain which space you want to preserve and which one do you consider an extra-space to be removed, if you can't specify exactly how to determine the line breaks or indentation you want to have, how do you expect others here to do that?

I'm using javax.xml.transform.Transformer  in my java code.
In the xml above in example I want to remove the extra-indentation in the line <java.version>17 you can see that it has 53 spaces instead of 8 to be aligned with  <vaadin.version>,  but I want to preserve the 2 empty-lines separating and sections, as well as the 1 line separating </parent> and </project>. I hope is clearer now, thank for your help

@MartinHonnen I edited my question adding the snippet I'm using in my code to give more context

Experiment with xsl:preserve-space and perhaps some template matching whitespace text nodes that uses translate to remove spaces. Then test whether adding or keeping xsl:output indent gives the wanted result. I don't think once you use xsl:strip-space you have a chance to preserve whitespace/line breaks, and xsl:output indent also allows the XSLT processor/serializer to add and elide white space. For instance Saxon (12), once I use xsl:output indent="yes", seems to eliminate the extra line breaks between elements.

Thanks for the tips, but I couldn't make it work. Maybe it's not possible as you point out, but I guess it's also my ignorance on this matter. I also asked ChatGPT, but all the examples it gave didn't work.

You could try to control the number of spaces for indentation by processing whitespace text nodes, the following attempts that (it is using XSLT 3, easy with Java by bringing e.g. Saxon HE 12 https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.saxon/Saxon-HE on the class path):
<xsl:stylesheet 
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
  
  <xsl:param name="indent-no-spaces" as="xs:integer" select="4"/>
  
  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:preserve-space elements="*"/>
  
  <xsl:output indent="no"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="text()[not(normalize-space())]">
    <xsl:value-of select="replace(., ' +', ((1 to (xs:integer($indent-no-spaces * count(ancestor::*))))!' ') => string-join())"/>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="text()[not(normalize-space())][not(following-sibling::node())]">
    <xsl:value-of select="replace(., ' +', ((1 to (xs:integer($indent-no-spaces * (count(ancestor::*) - 1))))!' ') => string-join())"/>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>

Sample online fiddle.
Take that as an example to adjust/tune to your needs, not as doing exactly what you want.

Thank you for suggesting such a smart solution. Unfortunately, I am unable to introduce new dependencies into the project. As a result, I need to work with the transformer provided in the JDK, which only supports XSLT 1.0.
